# How to add custom route what routes to existing folder ASP.MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have MVC project with standert folders, but I need to add custom folder what wil act the same as Scripts or Content. In other word - I need to serve files and folders in this folder in the same maner like those two.

Comment: As long as you don't set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` in your routing, static files will have priority to the routing. i.e. as long as static file exists, it will get around the routing and you don't have to worry about them. What is the type(extension) of files that you want to put in that folder?

Comment: @WeTTTT There is js, css and image files that design provider gave.

Comment: In this case, as long as you don't want to do some path rewriting, you can simply create the folder, dump all the files into it and you should be good. Just double check if you have `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` in your routing config. If so it can be slightly more complicated.